# Complex number set has least upper bound property?

Tags: complex-numbers

> **Exercise 1.9** Suppose $z = a + bi, w = c + di$. Define $z<w$ if $a<c$, and also if $a = c$ but $b<d$. Prove that this turns the set of all complex numbers into an ordered set. (This type of order relationis called a *dictionary order*, or *lexicographic order*, for obvious reasons.) Does this ordered set have the least upper bound property?

The solution of this question is the procedure this set has an ordered property such as "$x<y$ or $x=y$ or $x>y$", "$x<y$ and $y<z$ then $x<z$".

> Solution. We need to show that either $z<w$ or $z=w$, or $w<z .$ Now since the real numbers are ordered, we have $a<c$ or $a=c$, or $c<a .$ In the first case $z<w ;$ in the third case $w<z$. Now consider the second case. We must have $b<d$ or $b=d$ or $d<b .$ In the first of these cases $z<w$, in the third case $w<z$, and in the second case $z=w$.
> We also need to show that if $z<w$ and $w<u$, then $z<u$. Let $u=e+f i$ Since $z<w$, we have either $a<c$ or $a=c$ and $b<d .$ Since $w<u$ we have either $c<f$ or $c=f$ and $d<g .$ Hence there are four possible cases:
> Case 1: $a<c$ and $c<f$. Then $a<f$ and so $z<u$, as required. 
> Case 2: $a<c$ and $c=f$ and $d<g .$ Again $a<f$, and $z<u .$
> Case 3: $a=c$ and $b<d$ and $c<f$. Once again $a<f$ and so $z<u$.
>  Case $4: a=c$ and $b<d$ and $c=f$, and $d<g .$ Then $a=f$ and $b<g$, and so $z<u$

But I think that this question already gives us that this set is ordered, so we don't need prove it. In addition, all of ordered sets have a least-upper-bound property, so we also need not prove they have a least-upper-bound property. I think this book asks us a wrong question. Is it right?
ps. Why this solution doesn't prove there is a least upper bound?

Comment: Use MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: "... all of ordered sets have a least-upper-bound property..." **Utterly false**.

Comment: The exercise asks that you *prove* that the relation $<$ defined in the complex numbers *is in fact* a relation of order (verifies the properties...).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider the subset $\{(0,y)\,:\,y\in\Bbb R\}$.

Comment: Thank you. I realize that not all ordered sets have least upper bound property, but I don't know why this solution proves only whether this set is ordered or not.

Comment: @주혜민, because is **only** a proof of "$<$ is a relation of order". See you some related with the least-upper-bound property in https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8wBc.png?

Comment: @주혜민,  "I realize that not all ordered sets have least upper bound property..." then edit the question and delete the part "In addition, all of ordered sets have a least-upper-bound property..."

Comment: Sir, I didn't get your example! According to least upper bound property,  a non-empty set $E\subset \mathbb{C}$ which is bounded above must have supremum in $\mathbb{C}$. But in your example, the set you considered is not Bounded above. Please reply

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi, $C$ **is** bounded *in the lexicographic order*.

Comment: Sir did you mean $\mathbb{C}$?  then what are the bounds of $C$ under lexicographic order?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi, see the correction. Any $(x,\cdots)$ with $x > 0$ is an upper bound of $C$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your last comment. Got it :-)

Comment: What if I consider $\mathbb R$ to be the extended real number system consisting of the real field  $\mathbb R$ with $-\infty$ and $\infty$. Then I have $(0, \infty)$ as a supremum of this subset?

Comment: @RichardKYu, yes.